# Is there a way to split a String/Sequence using a sub-string/collection delimiter in Swift?

Tags: swift, search, collections, split, subsequence

I've seen various queries here on splitting a Swift string.  But they always deal with using either a single character or one of a set of individual characters to split the string.  How do I split one string with another?  For example, what if I want to split on CR-LF?  The analogous `Sequence`/`Collection` interfaces have the same problem, I can split on a single `Element` value, or one of a set of `Element` values, but not on a specific sub-sequence (actually, sub-collection since the value needs to be repeatedly visitable).

Is there some methods I'm missing?  Or do I have to manually search by looping through the receiver `Sequence` finding the first element of the matching `Collection`, then return only if the rest of the collection is found at that sequence point?

Comment: My guess is that the feature is too specific to be included in the standard library.